# How to create a splash screen with a UIActivityIndicator for a Tab bar application?

Tags: iphone

How to create a splash screen with a UIActivityIndicator for a Tab bar application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it over top of the tab bar. As in, add it as a subview to your window. Remove that view once you're ready. Unless of course you want to show the tab bar and just display a splash (such as some loading screen) for a view it displays, then do the same, but to the contained view not the window.